# Get default set Email of contact? Android programatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a contact. It has 3 emails. I saved second email as a default email of contact. How do I get that default email programmatically? Help Please. Thankyou

```
Here is the email string of the contact
```

[image]

```
Now I want to get this marked email:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The field you're looking for is [IS_SUPER_PRIMARY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY), here's a code to get the default email for a contact:

```
long contactId = <your contact id>;
Cursor c = getContentProvider().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Email.ADDRESS }, Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId + " AND " + Email.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " = 1", null, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
   Log.d(TAG, "email = " + c.getString(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is a way to get the default email programmatically except you give the user ability to select an email account, generally, the user's first email are mostly the default email but not always so.

If you want to still use the first email, you just return the first mail from the email account list returned

you can do this

> ```
>        public  String  getUserAccount(){
>         AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
>         Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
>         ArrayList<String> googleAccounts = new ArrayList<String>();
>         for (Account ac : accounts)
>         {
>             String acname = ac.name;
>             String actype = ac.type;
>             //add only google accounts
>             if(ac.type.equals("com.google"))  googleAccounts.add(ac.name);
>         }
>             String primaryAccount = googleAccounts.get(0);
>          return primaryAccount;
>       }
> ```
>
> This will return the first google email

Comment: Yup, its always returning the first email

Comment: I think the OP is talking about a contact on the phone, not the user's google accounts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = getContentProvider().query(Email.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Email.ADDRESS }, Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId + " AND " + Email.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " = 1", null, null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
   Log.d(TAG, "email = " + c.getString(0));
}
```

IS_SUPER_PRIMARY is the key to get this. hope this will solve your problem